# Disable the skip login option on PayPal API

Tags: javascript, paypal

I'd like to know if it's possible to **disable the skip login option** that appears when you get the login popup for a payment.

It's the option that says:

> For faster checkout, skip login for future purchases using this computer.

I've been fighting with JavaScript for a while now, and gotten most of what I need done, including automatically closing the window after a timeout.

It would be nice if PayPal included a way to inject approved code into your login page if you're using an app, so that way you can do custom things with it. Maybe something such as check for inactivity and auto close.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't currently a way to do this. Out of curiosity, why do you want to disable this feature? It's purpose is to reduce login friction, which should in turn increase conversion.

Comment: I want to disable it because I'm using this system on a kiosk. There are quite a few features I'd like to have available, such as:
disable auto-login
timeout (so the popup will auto close if there is no activity within a time frame). -With the ability to also call a response function on the parent. That way it would be able to tell the parent that the system timed out, not just cancelled.
temporary-cookies only (I think this is already happening).
customizable dynamic logo.

Comment: Edited:
I want to disable it because I'm using this system on a kiosk. There are quite a few features I'd like to have available, such as:
disable auto-login,
timeout (so the popup will auto close if there is no activity within a time frame) (With the ability to also call a response function on the parent. That way it would be able to tell the parent that the system timed out, not just cancelled),
temporary-cookies only (I think this is already happening), and 
customizable dynamic logo.

Comment: Sorry, but kiosk uses are not supported and will likely be flagged as fraud. It isn't secure to enter username/password into a device that you don't own. Instead you should check in to the mobile payments feature of PayPal Here. (https://www.paypal.com/here)